# Como Gravar a Data, Hora, Minuto E Segundo em C# WINFORMS e SQL SERVER?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Criei um sistema de vendas, e preciso que grave a data, hora, minutos e segundos.
Do jeito que fiz, só grava a data, e o resto vem 00:00:00.
Abaixo vai o código do que fiz:

```
//evento load do formulário vendas.
private void Vendafrm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmVenda.Start();//inicia o Timer
        PovoaGridVenda();//Povoa a grid das vendas
        PovoaCobCli();//Povoa a combobox dos clientes
        PovoaCobProd();//povoa a combobox dos produtos
    }
```

O resultado está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vai o formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método que grava:

```
//para gravar a venda
    public void GravaVenda()
    {
        tmVenda.Start();
        decimal entr = 0;
        VendaModel objVenda = new VendaModel();
        //objVenda.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpData.Value);
        objVenda.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpData.Value);
        objVenda.Desconto = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDesconto.Text);
        objVenda.Entreg = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEntreg.Text);
        objVenda.Falta = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFalta.Text);
        objVenda.IdCl = Convert.ToInt32(txtIdcl.Text);
        objVenda.IdPd = Convert.ToInt32(txtIdprod.Text);
        objVenda.Pago = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPago.Text);
        objVenda.Qtd = Convert.ToInt32(nudQuantd.Value);
        objVenda.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text);
        objVenda.Troco = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTroco.Text);
        try
        {
            if (cobCliente.Text == "")
            { MessageBox.Show("O nome do cliente é obrigatório!"); }
            else if (cobProduto.Text == "")
            { MessageBox.Show("O nome do produto é obrigatório!"); }
            else if (txtPreco.Text == "")
            { MessageBox.Show("O preço do produto é obrigatório!"); }
            else if (txtEntreg.Text == entr.ToString())
            { MessageBox.Show("O valor entregue não pode ser zero '0', nem menor que o total!"); } 
            else
            {
                vendaBll = new VendaBLL();
                int cod = Convert.ToInt32(vendaBll.GravaVenD(objVenda));
                txtId2.Text = cod.ToString();                    
                PovoaGridVenda();
                LimpaVenda();
                MessageBox.Show("Dados gravados com sucesso!");

                crFacturaVenda factura = new crFacturaVenda();
                factura.rad2.IsChecked = true;
                factura.txtImp.Text = txtId2.Text;
                factura.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu o seguinte erro ao gravar a venda: " + erro.ToString());
        }
    }
```

A tabela está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque não usa a função [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Lazy, vai a questão de cadastrar uma venda realizada no dia anterior?

Comment: Seria interessante você colocar o método que faz o Insert na sua tabela.

Comment: Coloca a definição da tua tabela com os tipos das colunas.

Answer (score 0):

Para receber a data / hora actual pode fazer:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
```

E para remover um dia basta colocar -1 na função **AddDays**

```
d1 = d1.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar o [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) nas propriedades dele você define que o [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format(v=vs.110).aspx) vai ser `Custom` e a propriedade [`CustomFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat(v=vs.110).aspx) você coloca `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Se você olhar no arquivo `Form1.Designer.cs` verás que ficou da seguinte forma a declaração do `DateTimePicker`.

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 53);
this.dateTimePicker1.Name = "dateTimePicker1";
this.dateTimePicker1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);
this.dateTimePicker1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Para pegar o valor digitado no campo, basta você usar a propriedade [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime data = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Comment: Fiz deste modo, não resultou. Acredito que o problema deve estar no uso do Timer, parece que alguma coisa não fiz directo.